# Setting Up A State in a FSM

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, fsm, state-machine

I'm using an class based FSM for the first time and I'm a little confused on what the best practice is to set-up the initial state.

I've added a FSM to my `Screen` class that I want to use to handle (mostly) transitions.  Traditionally I'd do something like this:

```
function update(frameTime : Number) : void
{
    switch(_currentState)
    {
        case STATE_TRANSITIONING_IN:
            slideTheButtonsIn();
            if(buttonsInPlace == true)
                changeState(STATE_ACTIVE);
        break;
        case STATE_ACTIVE:
            if(buttonClicked() == true)
                changeState(STATE_TRANSITIONING_OUT)
        break;
        case STATE_TRANSITIONING_OUT:
            slideButtonsOut();
            if(buttonsInPlace == true)
                removeThisScreen();
        break;
    }
}
```

I think that's a pretty standard approach.

So my problem with my new states are, WHO is responsible for creating all the objects on screen?  Should my `Screen` create all the buttons and stuff and then pass them to the `MainMenuTransitionInState` class or should the `MainMenuTransitionState` class create the buttons and then pass them around or have I missed the mark entirely?

Appreciate your sage advice here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A [model-view-controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) might help here.

`MainMenuScreen` (View)

This is what will display your model.  Work with all your UI related objects here.  Query the model directly to initialize or update them.

`MainMenuFsm` (Controller)

This is your view's event handler.  Whenever the user interacts with your view, translate the actions into updates to your model.

`MainMenuState` (Model)

Store your state here.